# How to permanently merge two tables in SQL Server based on key field?

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I have 2 tables within the same SQL Server databases that share a similar key field.

I need to create a new permanent table that is of these 2 tables merged together.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

I have 1 table that has over 200 columns and has a field called Meter_Number.

I then have another table that has around 100 columns that also has a field called Meter_Number.

I want to create a new table that combines these two tables based on this Meter_Number.

But not every record has a Meter_Number value, but I still need these in the table.

But the ones that do have a Meter_Number field need to be matched.

This is all customer information.

Comment: How do you mean "similar key"? Is the rest of the structure similar, or do they complement one other? Can you give a representative sample?

Comment: Can you explain your question little more? Give the schema definition of the tables you want to merge. What you want to accomplish? Give the schema definition of result table. What are the issues you  are facing with the current techniques you applied?

Comment: I added more information, hopefully it helps. Sorry for being so vague.

Comment: @GISer IS this a one time process or more then one time ??

Comment: One time process. And I lied about the columns in each table being unique, there are some duplicate column names.

Comment: @GISer Please see my updated answer I hope it will be usefull

Comment: Thanks for you help! I'm so new to SQL that I'm not really sure what I need to do to make your code work. Can you tell me what part I need to change? Sorry.

Comment: @GISer you need change table names .. except this all things should work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35294/discussion-between-dhaval-and-giser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @Sql1 varchar(MAX) -- if you are using SQL server 2000 then @Sql1 varchar(8000)
Declare @Sql2 varchar(MAX) -- if you are using SQL server 2000 then @Sql2 varchar(8000)

Set @Sql1 = ''

SELECT @Sql1 = @Sql1 + 'OLDTABLE1.' + c.name + ','
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'OLDTABLE1'

SELECT @Sql1 = @Sql1 + 'OLDTABLE2.' + c.name + ','
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'OLDTABLE2'
and c.name <> 'Meter_Number'

Set @Sql1 = LEFT(@Sql1, (Len(@Sql1) - 1))

Set @Sql2 = 'Insert into NEWTABLE( ' + @Sql1 + ')'
Set @Sql2 = @Sql2 + ' Select ' + @Sql1 + ' from OLDTABLE1 , OLDTABLE2 where OLDTABLE1.Meter_Number = OLDTABLE2.Meter_Number'

Print @Sql2
```

Comment: What if there are like more than 200 fields? How do I just have it do all of them? Thanks.